# How to run Mac OS X virtually on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, macosx

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 stable version
and oracle virtual box 4.1.2_ubuntu

Have a ISO file of snow leopard with me, 
When I run virtual box I got following error:

```
FATAL! Could not read from the boot medium!System halted.
```

I have Selected setting, storage, IDE controller  > snow leopard.

I have also run ISO file in vmware player, it shows me following message.

```
Operating system not found.
```

Still giving me an error, Did ISO image should be bootable or it is always?

Can anybody tell  from where i can download latest version of Mac OS x with Xcode.
Xcode is important for me.

Also any other good option to run Mac OS virtually on Ubuntu. If anyone have links for that please share.

Comment: Check out this SO question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-mac-os-x-in-a-virtual-machine

Comment: http://www.sysprobs.com/update-snow-leopard-1062-intel-amd-hazard-1064-virtualbox-328 check this installation process disabling EFI option and with a FIXED SIZE VIRTUAL PARTITION of 20GB.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First click new and enter the following settings:

[image]

I named it OSX 10.9, and chose Mac OSX and Mac OS X 10.9 Mavericks (64 bit). Chose the appropriate one for you. Click Next.

[image]

Give it a certain amount of RAM. I advise at least 2500 for OSX but don't go above half your available memory.

[image]

The following settings should all be default:

First chose Create a Hard Drive now.

[image]

Chose the top one.

[image]

Chose dynamically and then chose at least 10GB (I went for 15. You need a lot for Xcode - 30+).

[image]

Click create.

[image]

Click settings.

[image]

Click System

Untick all but CD/DVD and then move it to the top with the arrow keys.

Untick Enable EFI (special OSes only).

[image]

Click Display, and give it 16MB Video Memory (if you can). It has to be at least 8.

[image]

Click storage and then the Plus CD icon.

[image]

Click Chose disk.

[image]

Navigate to your OS X .iso file. It needs to be Hackintosh. I got mine from [here](https://www.hackintoshzone.com/). You have to disable adblock to get to it. (I used a torrent so it downloaded quicker - it is 5.5GB)

It is legal, but against what apple like you to do (as Mavericks is now free you don't need to pay anything. You can purchase an OSX 10.8 licence if you want, to make sure you are covered).

Click Open.

[image]

Click OK.

[image]

Click start and you can boot it.

[image]

Press Enter, and follow the installation process.

[image]

[image]

Complete the installation process. Then go back to Settings -> System -> Boot order, and disable CD/DVD and enable Hard Drive and move it to the top.

It will boot correctly. Finally, open the app store and install XCode from it (it's free).

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: Thanks for the great tute, there was only one thing missing for me, which was provided by the link in [@PhilippeGachoud](http://askubuntu.com/a/507635/6808)'s post: [Most of the time you can’t see the disk to select. Go to Disk utilities as shown below. ... Create a new partition and press Apply.](http://www.sysprobs.com/update-snow-leopard-1062-intel-amd-hazard-1064-virtualbox-328)