# What are the steps to install windows 7 on virtual box in ubuntu 14.4lts?I have version 4.3.10 virtual box and I do not see a extension pack for it

Tags: virtualbox

I want to install windows 7 on virtual box version 4.3.10 in ubuntu 14.04lts. I do not see a extension pack for this version. Will I need it to install windows and if so how can it be installed?

Comment: Download the iso and follow the steps [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/508623), just with the windows iso. Oh, and instead of an OSX 10.9 VM, add Windows 7 VM in the 2nd step.

Comment: Thanks. What I want to do is install windows 7 from a disk in virtual box version 4.3.10. From what I have read here I need a extension pack for this to work but I dont see one for this version of virtual box on the oracle site. What is the easiest way to do the installation?

Comment: I don't have an extension pack... It works for me.

Comment: Thanks, you’re right Tim. I installed Windows 7 in virtual box and its running fine.

Answer (score 0):

took me some time to find the Extensions

The version in Ubuntu is 4.3.10-93012 if you go straight to the latest you will get a version mismatch error. Here is the good one for the current version in 14.04LTS:

[VirtualBox Extension Pack-4.3.10-93012](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.10/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-4.3.10-93012.vbox-extpack)

Should there be an update it will most surely be a few versions behind the latest, thus bookmark this URL:  [Virtualbox Older Versions](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_3)