# Duel boot ubuntu and hackintosh

Tags: dual-boot, macosx

I have an Lenovo Yogo 2 Pro with ubuntu installed. I need a OS X install for app development. Is there any guides to install a hackintosh and dual boot ubuntu? If possible I would like to use grub to boot the OS X install.

Comment: Could you run OSX in a VirtualBox? http://askubuntu.com/questions/324509/how-to-run-mac-os-x-virtually-on-ubuntu-12-04/508623#508623

Comment: Yeah, I _could_ but I would rather just have the install. Partly because I would have the iOS emulator running inside of a VM using a lot of resources.

Comment: Ahh okay, yeah a VM in a VM... :)

Answer (score 1):

I chain load Chameleon via GRUB to launch OSX on my hackintosh.

First off download and extract [the Chameleon boot loader](http://chameleon.osx86.hu/). Then copy the file **i386/boot0** from the extracted archive to the directory **/boot/chameleon/** (it will need to be created). Now to create the custom GRUB menu entry edit the file **/etc/grub.d/40_custom** and below the hashes add:

```
menuentry "OSX (Chameleon)" {
insmod part_gpt
insmod hfsplus

#osx root drive
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 8feaok1cd8ed7b3f
#linux boot drive, contains boot loader
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=linux_root 914jk9f9-54ed-46d0-b360-d9cf8a479a39

chainloader ($linux_root)/boot/chameleon/boot0
}
```

You will need to change the UUID's to match that of your partitions containing OSX and Linux. To find the UUID of your OSX partition use the command (change /mnt/osx to where your OSX partition is mounted):

```
sudo grub-probe -t fs_uuid  /mnt/osx
```

and to find the UUID of your Linux root partition use

```
sudo grub-probe -t fs_uuid  /
```

After you have configured the custom menu entry run the following command to update GRUB:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot your system and you will have a entry in your GRUB boot menu to boot to OSX.